# Scrapy - Error binding parameter when writing item to sqlite table

Tags: sqlite, scrapy

When trying to insert the contents of a Scrapy item to a SQLite table, I get an error binding parameter

```
2015-10-27 22:57:09 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query=Ida> (referer: http://www.nieuwsblad.be/tv-gids/vandaag/film)
<type 'list'>
2015-10-27 22:57:09 [scrapy] ERROR: Error processing {'channel': [u'PRIME STAR'],
 'rating': [u'6.9'],
 'start_ts': [u'13:00'],
 'title': 'Ida'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/bertcarremans/Documents/Python/topfilms/topfilms/pipelines.py", line 15, in process_item
    self.storeInDb(item)
  File "/Users/bertcarremans/Documents/Python/topfilms/topfilms/pipelines.py", line 31, in storeInDb
    item['rating']
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

In pipelines.py, I wrote the function storeInDb to store the item:

```
def storeInDb(self, item):
    self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO topfilms(\
        title, \
        channel, \
        start_ts, \
        rating \
        ) \
    VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ? )",
    (
        item['title'],
        item['channel'],
        item['start_ts'],
        item['rating']
    ))
    self.con.commit()
```

And the table is create as follows:

```
def createTopFilmsTable(self):
    self.cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS topfilms(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, \
        title TEXT, \
        channel TEXT, \
        start_ts TEXT, \
        rating TEXT \
        )")
```

What format does rating need to be in order to have the code working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are passing lists to the table fields:

```
{'channel': [u'PRIME STAR'],
 'rating': [u'6.9'],
 'start_ts': [u'13:00'],
 'title': 'Ida'}
```

you need an item like:

```
{'channel': u'PRIME STAR',
 'rating': u'6.9',
 'start_ts': u'13:00',
 'title': 'Ida'}
```

so make sure on your spider that you are saving text instead of a list in the item fields, maybe you are assigning a `selector.extract()` directly to the item which is a common mistake, you should try `selector.extract()[0]` or maybe `''.join(selector.extract())` or `selector.extract_first()` with the latest `parsel` version on scrapy.